# JPA Cascade Persistence

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I want to store `Persons` with their `Cars` in the database. I use Spring 5.

The problem is that when I want to add a person with cars in the database, the 'person_id' field from the 'car' table is set to null instead of being set on the id of the created person.
That is weird because I even set that `nullable=false` in Car class.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Car> cars;

}

@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer carId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id",nullable=false)
    private Person person;
}



CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE car (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    person_id INT,
    ADD CONSTRAINT person_id REFERENCES person(id)
);
```

I use the `JpaRepository` to save a person:

```
Person p = new Person();
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
Car c1 = new Car();
Car c2 = new Car();

cars.add(c1);
cars.add(c2);
p.setCars(cars);
personJpaRepository.save(p);
```

Comment: you have not added the car to the person

Comment: suggestion keep mapping and db in sync: add a not null on person_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take advantage of the Cascade option you must remember to set the dependencies on both sides of the relationship.
Otherwise the persistence provider will not consider that as a relationship:

```
cars.add(c1);
cars.add(c2);

c1.setPerson(p);
c2.setPerson(p);

p.setCars(cars);
personJpaRepository.save(p);
```